# Rails calculate total time duration for days and week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, duration, calculation

I have a small time keeping app I am building using Rails 6.0.4. I ran:

```
rails g scaffold Meetings name:string start_date:datetime end_date:datetime duration:integer
```

The duration is a calculated field that I save to the database in my model meetings.rb:

```rb
before_save :set_duration

def daily_total_duration
  Meeting.where("start_date >= ? AND end_date  < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day).sum(:duration)
end

def weekly_total_duration
  Meeting.where("start_date >= ?", Time.now.beginning_of_week).sum(:duration)
end

def set_duration
  self.duration = (end_date - start_date).to_i
end
```

I am trying to calculate the total duration a meeting took per day and per week but I can't figure out the correct syntax of my method.

In my `Meeting` model I have the below 2 methods that don't seem to work:

```rb
def daily_total_duration
  Meeting.where("start_date >= ? AND end_date < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day).sum(:duration)
end

def weekly_total_duration
  Meeting.where("start_date >= ?", Time.now.beginning_of_week).sum(:duration)
end
```

In my meetings.index.html.erb I have for example:

```rb
<tbody>
  <% @meetings.each do |meeting| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= meeting.name %></td>
      <td><%= meeting.start_date %></td>
      <td><%= meeting.end_date %></td>
      <td><%= meeting.duration %></td>
      <td><%= duration_display meeting  %></td>
      **<td><%= meeting.daily_total_duration %></td>**
      **<td><%= meeting.weekly_total_duration %></td>**
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', meeting %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_meeting_path(meeting) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', meeting, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue as I can't seem to get the output I want working in the image below. For example I need to sum the duration of the first two rows (2021/8/01) as they are occurring on the same day but what is happening is the method is only summing the duration of the current day today (2021/8/01) = 57600 in the image below. It should instead be individual days.

[image]

Comment: In your query, `Meeting.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day).sum(:duration)`, did you mean to use `created_at` or `start_date`?

Comment: Hi Magzy yes you are correct i have edited my question but i cant seem to get this to work i get a no method error in Meeting#index   undefined method `daily_total_duration' for #<Meeting:0x0000560f29ac9fe8>

Comment: That issue means maybe there is nothing wrong with the query.

Comment: Can you post more code from `meeting.rb` file because I can't see an issue why the controller can't see the method `daily_total_duration` unless it is declared private?

Comment: It doesn't have the `daily_total_duration` in the `meeting.rb` file. Can you just edit the question with full `meeting.rb` code?

Comment: Hi Magzy i have updated the question i noticed i had spelling mistake and i needed to restart the server :( anyway i still cant get the desired outcome see above new image with wrong sum duration field. what is happening is the method is only summing the duration of the current day today (2021/8/01) = 57600 instead of individual days for some reason

Comment: I can't understand what it is that you're trying to acheive - what is "the total duration a meeting took per day and per week" even supposed to mean? If a meeting is unique (and not recorruing) that would always just be equal to the length of the meeting. Can you provide an example of the data and an expected result?

Comment: Is what you're actually looking for here to group the records per day?

Comment: Hi Max sorry for the confusion. Yes i am trying to group the meeting duration per day in one column and per week in another column so i can see the total time duration i spend in meetings for each day and each week. An example would be in the image above highlighted would be on the 2021/08/07 = 57600 (15 hours 0 mins) but its just showing the total greated for today and aplying that to all records

Comment: I think you don't get your desired output because you are using `Time.now.beginning_of_day` and `Time.now.beginning_of_week`. So you are executing the same query over and over which means "sum all meeting duration **today** and **this week**" but what you want to do is sum of all meeting durations **the meeting's day** and **the meeting's week**

Comment: You should do something like that: `Meeting.where("start_date >= ? AND end_date < ?", self.start_date.beginning_of_day, self.start_date.end_of_day).sum(:duration)`

Comment: Hi Magzy that is exactly what I was looking for its working perfectly thank you for the help you are great